# Requiring mocha test file in node.js cause TypeError: describe is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a test file containing certain test :

```
describe("tests", () => {
  before(async () => {
    //....
  });
  afterEach(async () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

And i want to require that file inside my node.js code:

```
const test = require(resolve('server.test'));
console.log(test);
```

but it's not working because of the following error :

```
TypeError: describe is not a function
```

I tried to export something from inside the test file like this :

```
// in the test file
module.exports.name = 11;

describe("tests", () => {
 // ....
});

// in node.js 
const name = require(resolve('server.test'));
const t = JSON.stringify(name);
console.log(t);
```

I'm still getting the same error

Comment: What if you do `const { describe, it} = require('mocha');` at the beggining of the test file?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek i don't have a problem in my test file, when i run the tests everything works fine. What i want here is to require the test file into my node.js code and extract from them

Comment: I understand but when you run your test file using `mocha` then all `describe()` and `it()` are valid functions because mocha defines them. However, when you `require()` your test file, then node does not have any idea that those functions are defined in the `mocha` module. For Node those are just some random functions which aren't even defined. That's why I suggested you to _define_ those functions in the test file so that both `mocha` and Node itself will recognize them

Comment: i added them at the beggining of my node.js code but still not working

Comment: as well as in my test file

Comment: Ok I just found in the docs (https://mochajs.org/#require) that _"The require interface cannot be run via the `node` executable, and must be run via `mocha`."_. So it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to `require` a test file in a regular code file, but if you *really* want to you can add a `describe` function to the [global namespace object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) so it exists when your test file is required:

```
if (global.describe === undefined) {  // if a global describe doesn't exist...
  global.describe = () => {};  // ...then define one
}
const test = require(resolve('server.test'));
console.log(test);
```

Comment: still not working, when i add the global.describe, it only return an empty object but then when i run npm test nothing works anymore for the test part so these changes influence the testing part

Comment: i get  global.describe is not a function

Comment: @brxnzaz good point, I updated my answer to check if `global.describe` is defined *before* creating the empty function so it doesn't overwrite the global `describe` provided by `mocha` during an actual test.